# Configured SSL is still using TCP Protocol

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have done ssl configuration for Apache ActiveMQ server as well as for Client which is working fine but when I checked in Wireshark tool it is still showing TCP.

why Wireshark tool is showing protocol as TCP instead of TLS? is there any problem with my configuration or any additional configuration is missing?

### activemq.xml

```
<sslContext>
            <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks"
                        keyStorePassword="password"
                        trustStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ts"
                        trustStorePassword="password"/>
        </sslContext>

        <transportConnectors>
                <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
                <transportConnector name="ssl"
                        uri="ssl://localhost:61714?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2&amp;needClientAuth=true" />

        </transportConnectors>

        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook"/>
        </shutdownHooks>
```

## Client Code

```
ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory("ssl://localhost:61714?socket.enabledProtocols=TLSv1,SSLv2");
        connectionFactory.setUserName(user);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        //Log.addInLog(Log.DBG, "ActiveMQ Connection url: "+url);
        connectionFactory.setKeyStore(new File("../apache-activemq-5.13.0/conf/client.ks").toURI().toString());
        connectionFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");
        connectionFactory.setTrustStore(new File("../apache-activemq-5.13.0/conf/client.ts").toURI().toString());
        connectionFactory.setTrustStorePassword("password");
        try{
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
        }catch(Exception e){
             Log.addInLog(Log.ERR, "Couldn't get conenction to ActiveMQ " + e);
             System.exit(1);
        }
        // Create the session
        this.transactedSession = transactedSession;
        session = connection.createSession(transactedSession, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        destination = session.createQueue(queueName);
```

Comment: Can you provide the Wireshark output that you're referring to?

Comment: 2295 33.847553037 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 **TCP** 66 61714 > 41700... ==>Protocol shown as TCP instead of TLSv1.2

Comment: @JustinBertram any findings?

Comment: I don't know enough about Wireshark to say whether or not that is the expected output and since you've only provided a single line of output in the comment (rather than modifying the question with a more complete explanation) I don't have any way to investigate further.

Comment: Is the traffic encrypted or in clear text? If you connect with a username and password can you read the password with Wireshark?